# PHP - Find an integer that is 8 digit long in a string between a range of numbers using preg_replace

Tags: php

I am trying to find an integer in a string that has the following characteristics:
- Is exactly 8 digits long
- Is between 21000000 and 22000000
- Or between 79000000 and 79999999

I want any number between those ranges to be redacted.

I tried using preg_replace. I'm not sure which pattern to use for this function.

Comment: and why `preg_replace`? do you want to replace all matched numbers with some other stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest this:

```
preg_replace('/(^|[^0-9]{1})(21[0-9]{6}|22000000|79[0-9]{6})([^0-9]{1}|$)/', '$1 |$2| $3', $str);

// (^|[^0-9]{1}) - set bordering character as non-numeric
// (21[0-9]{6}|22000000|79[0-9]{6}) - match the numbers range you need
// ([^0-9]{1}|$) make sure it doesn't include any other numbers
```

**NB!** Make sure you include $1 and $3 in your replace string, otherwise you'll lose chars surrounding the number.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<?php
 $str ="sdsds21000021dsds"; 
 $int = filter_var($str, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    if($int){       
      $number_of_digits = strlen((string)$int); 
      if($number_of_digits == 8){
      if((($int >= 21000000)&&($int <=22000000))||(($int >= 79000000)&&($int <=79999999))){
      echo $int;
           } else { // not found }
        } else { // not found }
      } else { // not found }
```

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to build a regular expression based on what you need.
Hope it helps!

```
\b21[0-9]{6}\b|\b79[0-9]{6}\b
```

- \b is word boundary
- {number} is repetition count
- 21 is interpreted literally, as 79 is
- [0-9] matches exactly one number in 0-9 range

test it here please if you need to tweak it.

https://regex101.com/